# N++ Regular expression - Swapping orders

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have task to swap sequential block orders, where I need to swap the orders:

```
    <!--Validate first group-->
     <lookupGroup name='Get 1st  value '>
        <Properties>
            <select property='A' field='B[0]'/>
        </Properties>
    </lookupGroup>
    <Include>..\Value\Test1.xml</Include>
    <Include>..\Value\Test2.xml</Include>
    <Include>..\Value\Test3.xml</Include>
    <Include>..\Value\Test4.xml</Include>
```

So above written needs to be in reverse order:

```
    <Include>..\Value\Test2.xml</Include>
    <Include>..\Value\Test3.xml</Include>
    <Include>..\Value\Test4.xml</Include>

    <!--Validate first group-->
     <lookupGroup name='Get 1st  value '>
        <Properties>
            <select property='A' field='B[0]'/>
        </Properties>
    </lookupGroup>
    <Include>..\Value\Test1.xml</Include>
```

what would be the right syntax for it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: `sequential block orders`:can you elaborate on that..

Comment: Is it always from the start of `<!--Validate first group-->` to the end of the first `Include` tag you want to move? Is there always only exactly 4 `Include` tags? If not, is there something noticeable that always comes after it (even any different tag will do)?

Comment: in order to elaborate - all i am trying to do is move all <Include> tags and data above the <lookupGroup>. Yes I have tried : (<\/lookupGroup)((<Include.*)(</Include>))   and my idea was to replace \2\r\n\1 but it didnt work. meanwhile I am not expert on Notepad++ regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex works on your example data, and will move the Include elements above the lookupGroup one at a time each time you hit Replace.  Hope this helps.

Find what: `( *<lookupGroup.*lookupGroup>.*\n)([^\n]*<Include>.*<.Include>)\n?`

Replace with: `\2\n\1`

For this to work, you have to have "." set to match newline.